# Determining whether a line between two points in a monotone polygon is a valid diagonal

Tags: computational-geometry

Given a [monotone polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_polygon), with it's vertices given in counter-clockwise orientation, is there any fast process to determine whether the line between two vertices of that polygon `A` and `B` is a valid diagonal of that polygon? A valid diagonal is a line between those two vertices that lies inside the polygon and doesn't intersect or touch any edge of the polygon.

Note : I need to be able to do this checking in constant time for triangulating the monotone polygon in linear time.

Comment: "of" _what_ "triangle"? ​ ​

Comment: It should be 'that polygon' instead, edited that.